# Volume of a Parametric Surface

Tags: vector-analysis, volume, parametric

[image: Cone with a radius of 1.5cm and a slant height of 3.5cm]

The cone pictured above has a radius of 1.5cm and a slant height of 3.5cm. Letting $\alpha=\arcsin\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)$ and $h=3.5\cos\alpha$, I have parametrized the cone in two ways:

$r(t,u)=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \left(\frac{3}{2h}\right)t\cos u \\ \left(\frac{3}{2h}\right)t\sin u\\t \end{bmatrix},\ t\in[0,h],\ u\in[0,2\pi]$

$r(\rho,\varphi,\theta)=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \rho\cos\theta\sin\varphi \\ \rho\sin\theta\sin\varphi \\ \rho\cos\varphi \end{bmatrix},\ \rho\in[0,h\sec\varphi],\ \varphi\in[0,\alpha],\ \theta\in[0,2\pi]$

With $r(t,u)$, and noting that $r_t=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}r(t,u)$, I can find the surface area, $SA$, of the cone by

$SA=\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^h ||r_t\times r_u||\ dt\ du$.

With $r(\rho,\varphi,\theta)$, I can find the volume, $V$, of the cone by taking the vectors $r_{\rho}$, $r_{\varphi}$, and $r_{\theta}$, putting them together to form a matrix $J_r$ (the Jacobian of $r(\rho,\varphi,\theta)$) and letting $G=(J_r)^TJ_r$, I take the $\det(G)$ and my volume is given by

$V=\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\alpha}\int_0^{h\sec\varphi}\sqrt{\det(G)}\ d\rho\ d\varphi\ d\theta$.

What I hope someone can inform me on, however, is how to find the volume of the cone using $r(t,u)$ rather than $r(\rho,\varphi,\theta)$. I've scowered the internet on how to find the volume of a parametric surface, but, to no avail. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Why not just use the equation $V = \pi r^2 h/3$?

Comment: I'm performing the calculation in this tedious manner in order to better my understanding of vector-calculus. I'm familiar with $V=\displaystyle\frac{\pi r^2 h}{3}$

Comment: Can you say more in more detail what's meant by the _volume of a parametric surface_? If you're thinking of the cone as a paper cup and the volume as liquid the cup can hold, it's still necessary to have some volume integral to evaluate.

Comment: Certainly. What I'm referring to is the volume bounded by the parametric surface $r(t,u)$; in your analogy, the volume of the liquid the cone can hold. Can a volume integral of $r(t,u)$ be taken and if so, how?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. If it matters, a parametric surface doesn't generally specify a volume. Think of this cone, for example, but with the top cut off by a slanted plane, or by some non-planar curve. "Volume" might refer to the maximum volume of liquid the surface holds for some definition of "horizontal", or it might refer to the volume of the convex hull of the surface, or perhaps something else. The point is, we need more information than just the parametric surface to specify (and to calculate) a volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you are parametrizing the lateral surface of the cone and in the second, you are defining the interior points too. In general, it is unnecessary to parametrize the surface to find the volume bound. But if you were given a parametrized surface with appropriate bounds, you could of course use it to find the volume, just like you would do if for example, cone was given as $z \tan \alpha = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, 0 \leq z \leq h$. So in this case,

$r(t,u)=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \left(\frac{3t}{2\sqrt{10}}\right)\cos u \\ \left(\frac{3t}{2\sqrt{10}}\right)\sin u\\t \end{bmatrix},\ t\in[0,h],\ u\in[0,2\pi]$

(please note there is a mistake in your parametrization)

$ \displaystyle V = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^h \int_0^{3t / (2 \sqrt{10})} r ~ dr ~ dt ~ du$

See the variable $r$ and its bounds for every $t$ and $u$, which is radius of the cross section of the cone at height $t$.

Comment: If you could direct me to my mistake in my parametrization, it'd be greatly appreciated. Also, is the introduction of a new variable $r$ necessary? I've tried looking at the Divergence Theorem as that relates a volume integral to a surface integral but am unsure on how to proceed with $r(t,u)$ to find its volume.

Comment: @Ama that's a completely different point and a different approach. Assume a vector field $\vec F = (x, 0, 0)$. Its divergence is $1$ so if you close the region with a disk at $z = 1$ and evaluate surface integral of $\vec F$ over the lateral surface of the cone and the disk at $z = 1$, it would be equal to the volume of the cone. Now another point to note is that the surface integral over the disk at $z = 1$ is in fact zero and that leaves you with only evaluating surface integral over lateral surface.

Comment: @Ama if you try evaluating and get stuck, pls ping here